# A .png Image Set convert A .raw File in Python

Tags: python, image, file, rawimage

I have this images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And I have lots of images  I will use 3d reconstructions these images but I sould convert one .raw file these images 
How can I use ?

Comment: Please formulate your question more clearly. Just to make sure, I assume these images are from yourself?

Comment: You can access to this images for this link :https://nihcc.app.box.com/v/ChestXray-NIHCC/folder/37178474737

Comment: I still don't understand your question. The images in the downloadable .tar.gz archives are PNG. What do you want to convert them to?

Comment: I want to convert .raw file because they are.png file

Comment: There is no such thing as .raw file format, you need to be more precise. Every camera manufacturer has a different RAW format, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format. Apart from that, it doesn't make much sense to go from .png to raw, only the other way around.

Comment: My code needs .raw file for running Can I convert my images to dicom files ??

Comment: No, you need to request DICOM files directly from the hospital.